# Brute-force search for solution to an unsolved mathematical inequality

Tags: c++, performance, mathematics, boost

From this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Unsolved_problem), the following unsolved problem is presented as a 
result of [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem):

[image: {\displaystyle 3^{k}-2^{k}\left\lfloor \left({\tfrac {3}{2}}\right)^{k}\right\rfloor >2^{k}-\left\lfloor \left({\tfrac {3}{2}}\right)^{k}\right\rfloor -2}]

It has been proven that a finite number of *k* exist, and so far **none are known**. The follow code is meant to brute-force search for a solution:

```cpp
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
//#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float<1000>> arbFloat;

enum returnID {success = 0, precisionExceeded = 1};

int main(){
    arbFloat k;

    for(k = 6; pow(3, k) - (pow(2, k) * floor(pow(1.5, k))) <= pow(2, k) - floor(pow(1.5, k)) - 2; ++k);

    if(pow(3, k) - (pow(2, k) * floor(pow(1.5, k))) <= pow(2, k) - floor(pow(1.5, k)) - 2){
        std::cout << "Solution at k = " << k << ".\n";
        return returnID::success;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Error: Precision exceeded at k = " << k << ".\n";
        return returnID::precisionExceeded;
    }
}
```

I am using the Boost multiprecision library `cpp_dec_float`, which works for large integers **and** decimals. The data type needs to be able to work with integers, because the solution for *k* needs to be a *positive integer*. The data type needs to work with decimals because `(3/2)^k` (equivalently `1.5^k`) returns a decimal.

In the code I have commented out the `cmath` library, because it appears to be included in `boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float`.

In the for-loop, I use `<=` to be equivalent to the *pseudocode* `!>`.

After the for-loop, I re-check if it is a solution because currently if the precision is exceeded, it breaks the for-loop. The if-else checks if it is has either exceeded precision or is an actual solution.

The precision in this example code is `1000` (line 5), but this is changed manually as I search for larger and larger numbers that may be a solution.

**I am trying to squeeze every ounce of speed out of this code, so any optimizations that make it quicker will be of great help!**

I am running this code on Ubuntu 16.04, and I compile it using `g++` with the `-Ofast` flag for the highest possible optimization during compilation.

Thanks!

Comment: The wikipedia article says "there can only be a finite number of such k", not that there exist a finite number of k.  Therefore I would think that it is likely for no such k to exist at all.  Additionally, according to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem), it is proven that if k exists, it must be > 471,600,000.  So you should start from there instead of 6.

Comment: You may consider openmp/mpi to parallel the computation.

Comment: @JS1 It is conjectured, *but not proven*, that no *k* exist. While I understand that in practical use I would start from k≈471600000, I set k=6 for simplicity, which I thought would result in the best answers regarding my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A first step in optimizing would be to avoid computing the same values multiple times.

Secondly, I would drop the floating point arithmetic altogether. You have integer bases with integer exponents, so use integers. \$(\frac{3}{2})^k\$ = \$\frac{3^k}{2^k}\$ and applying floor also results in an integer.

I'm not familiar with the problem at hand, but the mention that *none are known* leads me to think that the values might be quite higher than 1000, otherwise a solution would have been trivial to find.

Comment: Yes, indeed it is quite higher than 1000. So far, with the code that I have in my question, I have reached 17073 with no solution after **two hours** of computation (likely because 3^17073 is such a frightfully large number with over 8000 digits). This is with 3000 decimal places as well!

Comment: After improving my code with your suggestions in mind, it runs **far** quicker! I simply defined two variables, inside of the for loop, to be equal to 3^k and 2^k, and supplemented them in the equality check. Now, instead of taking hours it just took twenty seconds to reach the same point as I said in my previous comment!